# Intercept a constructor by creating a new constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have an object in which every key's value is an constructor.

```
const obj = {
    a : [Function: aConstructor],
    b : [Function: bConstructor],
}
```

I want to create another object `obj2` which will be exposed to other services, and based on the input provided to `obj2` it will call the corresponding `obj1` constructor with modified params.

```
_.each(obj, (value, key) => {
    obj2[key] = function A(message) {
         if(message===null)
            message = "MY CUSTOM MESSAGE";
         value(message)
    }
});
```

Use case :

```
const a = new obj2.a(null) 
//this should call the obj.a constructor with message "MY CUSTOM MESSAGE"
```

So i just want to intercept the constructors in `obj` and call it again with modified input params.
Please let me know if the question is not clear enough?

Comment: What it looks like is that you want to use `class` and `super`?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

What I did :

- Finding the chosen constructor in `obj[key]` instead of `obj.value`
- Using `Function.prototype.call` to call the chosen constructor and pass it the `this` reference to the instance I want to create

```js
const obj = {
    a : function (message) {
      console.log("constructor a, message : " + message);
      this.message = message;
    },
    b : function (message) {
      console.log("constructor b, message : " + message);
      this.message = message;
    },

} 


var obj2 = {};

_.each(obj, (value, key) => {
    obj2[key] = function A(message) {
         if(message===null) {
            message = "MY CUSTOM MESSAGE";
         }
         obj[key].call(this, message);
    }
});

const a = new obj2.a(null);
console.log("a = ", a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```